# How update Ext.Window

Tags: extjs3

I have gridpanel and for each row buttons with handler like (with chooser.js)

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/view/chooser.html

in html button:

```
function deleteImage(data){
   window.open("http://host/delete_file.php?file="+data.url,"_self");
};

function choose(btn){
    if(!chooser){
            chooser = new ImageChooser({
                    url:'http://host/get-images.php?path='+r.get('dtp'),
                    width:600,
                    height:350
            });
    }
    chooser.show(btn.getEl(), deleteImage);
};
                                            btn = new Ext.Button({
                                                             renderTo: id2,
                                                             text: 'Удалить',
                                                             width: 75,
                                                             handler: choose
                                            });
```

If i cancel window(with image) and open on another row then openning first window with first images(not from new row).

In chooser.js cancel button:

```
                            {
                                    text: 'Cancel',
                                    handler: function(){ this.win.hide();},
                                    scope: this
                            }
```

not close.

How after open new window update content(images from new row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working:

```
function choose(v){
        new ImageChooser({
                url:'http://host/get-images.php?path='+r.get('dtp'),
                width:600,
                height:350
        }).show(v, deleteImage);
  };
                                             new Ext.Button({
                                                         renderTo: id2,
                                                         text: 'Удалить',
                                                         width: 75,
                                                         handler: choose
                                        });
```